# Django 'int' object has no attribute 'status_code'

Tags: django

I start with def start method, it calls go_adder to add the num value 5 times in the adder.html until num equals 5. After that, the adder method should return ready=1

In views.py

```
def start(request):
    num=0
    ready_or_not=go_adder(num)
    return HttpResponse("Ready: %s "%str(ready_or_not))

def go_adder(num):
    ready=0
    if num<5:
        return render_to_response('adder.html',{'num':num})
    elif num==5:
        ready=1
        return ready

def check_post(request,num):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        num+=1
        return adder(num)
```

When I try to run this snippet code, it works until my "num=5", Then I get that error :

```
'int' object has no attribute 'status_code' 
Exception Location: C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\middleware\common.py in process_response, line 94
```

and Traceback says:

```
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py in get_response
                response = middleware_method(request, response) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\middleware\common.py in process_response
        if response.status_code == 404: ...
▶ Local vars
```

How can I fix that error ? Could you please help me ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The django views need to return an `HttpResponse` object. You are doing that while `num < 5`, but then you return an int when `num == 5`:

```
def adder(num):
    ready=0
    if num<5:
        num+=1
        # This renders the template and returns and HttpResponse; good
        return render_to_response('adder.html',{'num':num})
    elif num==5:
        ready=1
        # DONT RETURN AN INT HERE. RETURN AN HttpResponse
        return ready
```

If all you want for when `num==5` is to return a plain text response of the number 1, then you can return an HttpResponse and set the content type:

```
    elif num==5:
        ready=1
        return HttpResponse(str(ready), content_type="text/plain")
```

### Update 1

Based on our conversation, you have suggested that you want the view to constantly pass along the count value no matter what, and that you are POST-ing the `num` value in the actual form. If the number is less than 5 it should return one kind of template, otherwise it should return another kind of template.

You can combine your two different views into one that will handle both the original GET request when the page is first loaded, and the POST request submitted by your form. Just make sure to point your form at that same page.

```
def check(request):
    num = 0

    if request.method == 'POST':
        num = int(request.POST.get('num'))

    return adder(num)

def adder(num):
    if num < 5:
        num += 1
        tpl_name = 'adder.html'
    else:
        tpl_name = 'print.html'

    return render_to_response(tpl_name, {'num':num})
```

- `check()` is your single view.
- `adder()` is the helper function that will add the value, check it, and return an `HttpResponse` object based on that value. You must always return this from your view to the client.
- Both templates will be passed the context containing the value of `num`

### Update 2

You said that you are actually passing in your `num` through the url and not through the POST form. Small adjustment to the last example. You don't even need an `adder()` anymore. You only need a single view.

Set your url to  have an optional `num` pattern:

**urls.py**

```
(r'^checker/(?P<num>\d+)$', 'myapp.views.check')
```

**views.py**

```
def check(request, num=0):
    num = int(num)
    if num < 5:
        num += 1
        tpl_name = 'adder.html'
    else:
        tpl_name = 'print.html'

    return render_to_response(tpl_name, {'num':num})
```

Your "checker" url now has an optional number. If it is not passed in the url, it will be a value of `0` in the view. If you send it as a POST request, it will add and return a different template.

Comment: Your examples are not clear. Why is `go_adder` returning different types of objects? Which of those 2 views are you calling?

Comment: Cause, I want to repeat that process until I reach the value of 5. Before that, I call adder.html, once it is called 5 times, return a ready bit that is 1. Is there another way to do that ?

Comment: Your logic here should work, but your return value does not. What **should** happen if `num` reaches 5? A different template? And `int` is not an appropriate return value. Do you simply want it to return a plain/text response with the number 1?

Comment: Ok, I see your point. How can I get that value from my start method? , because I need to process that ready value over there.

Comment: It seems that your page never returns to the `start` view beyond the first GET, because you are sending it to another view.

Comment: Ok, in order for me to suggest an alternative, I need to figure out what you really want... I feel like really you only need one view that will check if its a post request, otherwise show the original start. That way you will access all of the data from the same view. Does that sound like what you want?

Comment: I also need to count displaying "adder.html: number such as 5?

Comment: I don't know what that means. What is supposed to be returned to the user if num is 5? Please tell me EXACTLY

Comment: if num is 5, and "adder.html" is displayed 5 times. Return nothing to user, continue to program where you left off

Comment: That makes no sense. You just want to return an empty response? Return nothing to the user? Continue to program where what left off? I don't think you have a very strong grasp of the django framework concepts. Is there something you are not telling me, like is this being used in an AJAX request?

Comment: Okay, you might be right, I am trying to learn. Please do not discourage me..... let's return another pages(print.html) saying "you are ready",Does that make sense ?

Comment: Ok, and last question...are you actually submitting your `num` in your POST form as a value, or are you just doing an empty POST and passing it through the URL like "/foo/5" => num=5

Comment: Thanks for your effort, I actually do not submit num, I misunderstood you, sorry my bad.... Anyway I will accept as an answer... Could you please help me for the case passing num through URL ?